# Default Options for symfony 2 forms are being overridden not merged

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

I have a custom form type that defines some default `attr` options:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'invalid_message' => 'The selected image does not exist',
        'attr'=>array(
            'data-image-picker'=>'true',
            'data-label'=>'Pick Image'
        ),
    ));
}
```

However when i use this custom form type the entire `attr` array is replaced with what is defined.

```
$builder->add('logo','image_picker',array(
    'attr'=>array(
        'data-label'=>'Logo'
     ),
 ));
```

When the form is rendered it only has `<input data-label="Logo" ...>`

How do i get it so that those options will be merged not completly overridden?

Comment: This is the expected behavior because you override the default value for the `attr` option and not the elements inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find these in the `options` array passed as the second argument to the `buildForm` method of your custom type.  You would want to do something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $options['attr']['data-label'] = 'Logo';
    ...
```